# What's the difference between VD, UI and UX?

Tags: terminology, dynamic-ui

I want to have a clear understanding of difference between user interface, user experience  and visual design.

Answer (score 3):

**User interface** is all the interactions between a user and a machine: steering wheel, buttons, mouse, keyboard, screen, joystick, sounds... When not specified the machine is a computer and the interface a [graphical user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).

**Graphic design** (or visual design) is the process of creating visual forms to pass a message.

**User experience** is how these interactions (visual forms being part of it) affect the user.

Comment: The user experience also involves what is NOT actually in the interface to start with ( because user requirements haven't been fully researched )

Comment: I am defining user experience not user experience design. That said, user experience is all the emotions of the user and its memories of it while and after using a machine therefore the wind, the surrounding noises or whatever you can think off affects its emotions.

You cannot define something by saying it is everything (the interface and not the interface).